# JBoss Tools: javax.servlet.* could not be resolved

Tags: java, jboss, httpsession

The namespace javax.servlet.* could not be resolved in Eclipse.
I'm using Eclipse for Java EE developers + JBoss Tools.

Any idea for a clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

check that your classpath includes lib for servlet-api.
It can be seen in .classpath file in your project directory.
It looks like classpathentry kind="lib" path="extlib/servlet-api.jar"/